# Manual Performance Testing

Tags: manual-testing, performance, load-testing

I created an application. And I want that application to accept 100000 users.

How can I perform manual performance testing on application?

Comment: What kind of application? Web, mobile or desktop? Why you think you need to test for 100k users? How many users do you have now?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is near impossible to generate a load of 100000 users manually.

Once I have tried to mimimic 50 users manually on a Citrix desktop application using a couple of desktops and two testers. We kept repeating the most heavy actions in our application to check the servers would handle it. In the end the results where wild guesses and unsatisfying, but we sort-of knew we could handle the users on our new server setup.

Research performance testing tools to generate load. My personal favorite web-based load-test tool is [Funkload](https://funkload.nuxeo.org/). The most used and popular seems [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for the web.

You wont get 100k users overnight. Monitor your servers and scale slowly as your user base grows. I think you are thinking about [premature optimizations](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the suitability of using Jmeter to do this testing. You certainly can't do it manually.

There are plenty of online tutorials for Jmeter. The main Jmeter site is actually very good http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html

For your 100,000 user test, you need to work out what the purpose of the test is.
What do you want these users to do?

Is this simply a 'break it' test? Are you trying to work out the maximum number of users the application can take?
If you think it's 100,000 then you need to start significantly below that and work up.

If you need to maintain 100,000 users on the site at the same time, think about how those users may be using the site. What actions will they be carrying out?

Look up some threads on here about resource/load profiling for performance testing. This will help you formulate a plan for testing this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you know JMeter is a fit? You do not know if the question is about Mobile, Web or Desktop application as this was not specified.

Comment: Based on the little information given I would go for Jmeter. Where I currently work we have used Jmeter for web applications and desktop. I will however edit my response slightly based on your comment.

Comment: Cool wasnt aware people use JMeter for desktop testing, seems you need to record the HTTP calls. Still might not be suited, but with the new wording I will vote it up to get question answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like jmeter to generate the users, however you will need multiple processes, machines, servers, etc.  This is consdierable undertaking, hard to answer in our Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this manually, you will need a load testing tool for it. The most popular free and open source load testing tools as of now are:

- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for main features highlighted and compared.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  [Locust](http://locust.io/)  which is An open source load testing tool.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how this will solve Askers problem?

Comment: How do you know Locus is a fit? You do not know if the question is about Mobile, Web or Desktop application as this was not specified.